# Canvas, KineticJs, Squares bouncing leaving the edge when i leave tab

Tags: kineticjs

I there guys, im relative new to canvas and kineticjs, like about 1 month, my english is poor i say sorry for that.

My problem: squares bouncing outside the edge of the canvas.

The squares leave the edge WHEN I change the tab or minimize explorer.
image example: http://clip2net.com/s/2aLYf

I change the tab like 5 seconds, then the squares ignores the edges, and if i return to 
the animation, the squares begin to return inside the limits.
So the edge is ignored, when I'm not watching the animation or the animation tab is not active.

the squares return when im watch again the tab.

My code is down

```
    function init_squares(){
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
  container: "square_animation",
  width: 150,
  height: 150
});

var stage_width = 150;
var stage_height = 150;

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
var num_squares = 12;

var squares = [];

    //creates the squares
for(var i=0; i < num_squares; i++){
            var this_width = get_width();
    squares[i] = new Kinetic.Rect({
                  x: stage_width / 2 ,
                  y: stage_height / 2,
                  width: this_width,
                  height: this_width,
              fill: get_color(),
          vy: get_random_speed(),   //custom values for the use of velocity
          vx: get_random_speed(),   //custom values for the use of velocity
           alpha: .7
    });
}

initialize_squares(); //initialize the squares
    function initialize_squares(){
    var n = squares.length;
    for(var i=0; i < n; i++){
        layer.add(squares[i]);
    }
    stage.add(layer);
}

//animation frame   
stage.onFrame(function(frame) {

    var n = squares.length;
    for(var i=0; i < n; i++){
        var attr = squares[i].getAttrs();
        var new_x =  squares[i].getX() + (attr.vx * frame.timeDiff / 1000);
        var new_y =  squares[i].getY() + (attr.vy * frame.timeDiff / 1000);
        var x = squares[i].getX();
        var y = squares[i].getY();

        //check right border
        if((x + attr.width) > stage_width){
            if(attr.vx > 0)
                attr.vx *= -1;
        }
        //check left border
        if(x <= 0){
            if(attr.vx < 0)
                attr.vx *= -1;
        }

        //check top border
        if(y <= 0){
            if(attr.vy < 0)
                attr.vy *= -1;
        }

        //check bottom border
        if((y + attr.width) > stage_height){
            if(attr.vy > 0)
                attr.vy *= -1;
        }

        squares[i].setY( new_y);
        squares[i].setX( new_x);
        squares[i].setAttrs({vx: attr.vx, vy: attr.vy});
    }
    layer.draw();
});
stage.start();  

function get_random_speed(){
    if( (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1) % 2 == 0)
        return (Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 40) * -1;
    else
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 40;
}

function get_color(){
    var colors = ['#c8c8c8','#b7b7b7','#ababab','#999999','#d2d2d2','#818181','#8f8f8f'];
    var n = colors.length;
    return colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * n)];
}

function get_width(){
    var widths = [20,22,24,28,26];
    var n = widths.length;
    return widths[Math.floor(Math.random() * n)];
}
    }
```

this is the site im working, the squares is down of the menu.
http://uniformestoro.com/

THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR HELP

Answer (score 0):

After a quick look at your code, I think the problem is calculating the position and then checking for collision on each frame. Thus when you don't look at the tab, no frame is rendered and therefore, when you look at it again, your objects will draw outside the box (because frame.timeDiff grows quite big meanwhile, so they move alot) and then start moving the direction they would if they just collided with the edge. I suggest you first first calculate how much time they need to hit the edge, if they hit it, then use the remaining time for the movement away from the edge. (this also solves problem when you have extreme fps drops, which would cause the code to behave different in the same way!)